# what is the purpose of Yaml files in Perl? and how to use them?

Tags: perl, yaml

what is the purpose of YAML files? and how to use them?

In one of our project YAML file is getting used to create the sample job files, which are getting consumed by Perl scraper as an input.

can anybody please explain how YAML file works and get executed(?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML is nothing but a Human readable data serialization format. It is a data serialization language that's easy to read and can serialize the common Perl variables.
You can find the use and simple example on YAML [here](http://perltricks.com/article/29/2013/9/17/How-to-Load-YAML-Config-Files) and 
[here](http://www.yaml.org/)

Answer (score 1):

[YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) is a human-readable data serialization format.  It doesn't get executed, it just allows showing/storing a data structure in plain text.